# How do you "target" emotes

Tags: overwatch

I have seen this done, but I have no idea how to do it, and Google is not helpful (probably searching wrong).

Sometimes, players use emotes like

> PlayerX says hello to PlayerY

but whenever I use the "Hello" emote, it just prints

> Me says hello

How can I "target" emotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hover over the circle indicating the emote over the desired player and press  <kbd>F</kbd>  in order to respond to that specific command. <kbd>F</kbd> is by default the "Understood/Agree" command.

You can "agree" with almost any voice line, including Ultimate Status, Health Needed, Hellos, and Voice Lines.

Comment: This answer doesn't make a lot of sense on console. What do you mean "hover over the circle indicating the emote"?

Comment: @DCShannon When your teammate uses a command from the command wheel a small circular bubble with the chosen command pops up over their heads for a small amount of time.

Comment: 'hover' = 'aim', then? Aim at them?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Retrosaur's answer, if you hover your crosshair over another player (even when they don't show the emote icon) and execute an emote it will be directed towards them, similar to your example.

> PlayerX says hello to PlayerY

You see your second example when an emote is executed with no player in your crosshair.

> Me says hello